# Object reference not set to an instance of an object. - SagePayV3Server.GetServerPaymentRequest

Tags: vb.net, server, integration, opayo

When using the SagePay Integration Kit (Standard) for a server implementation, using the suggested code to send the payment data to the test server invokes and object reference not set to an instance of an object error.

```
ServerPaymentResult = integration.GetServerPaymentRequest(ServerPaymentRequest, 
    SagePaySettings.ServerPaymentUrl);
```

App written in vb.net vb.net.
Do I need to override GetServerPaymentRequest?  The example provided didn't do so?  (on sagepay site)

```
Dim integration As SagePayIntegration
Dim serverPaymentResult As IServerPaymentResult = payment.GetServerPaymentResult()
Dim serverPaymentRequest As IServerPayment = payment.GetServerPaymentRequest()
'populate serverPaymentRequest Object
```

Comment: Set a break-point on the line where the exception occurs. Then run the code. When it stops at the break-point, hover the mouse over the variables, and you will see their values. You will find the one that is `Nothing`. This is the one which you must initiailze with `New SomeClassType` before attempting to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not familiar with the SagePay Integration Kit, but I am familiar with the object reference not set to an instance of an object error. This would probably occur with for example:

> Dim integration as SagePayIntegration = New SagePayIntegration

This would have to be done before setting any of the objects you use to a certain value. Try this with all of the objects you create for the SagePay Integration and it may work.